# How to map a AWS S3 bucket as a mapped drive (Network Drive) in windows server 2016

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, network-drive, mapped-drive, mount-point

I would like to use S3 bucket as a real-time file store and I wanted to upload/download large files to S3 from my Windows server 2016 frequently. Is there any option to mount an S3 bucket with windows EC2 instance without using third party paid tools

Comment: Robin, I am facing the same problem, did you found the solution?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use a combination of rclone, winfsp and NSSM to mount the bucket as drive read my answer here 
[Mount s3 bucket in ec2 windows instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33141468/mount-s3-bucket-in-ec2-windows-instance)